# Doubt regarding Universal set and union of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A question in my textbook is as follows:-
**Que. A survey shows that 76% of the Indians like oranges, whereas 62% like bananas. What percentage of the Indians like both oranges and bananas?**
My approach is  $n(U)=100$ and $n(A∪B)≤n(U)$.
Solution demands $n(A∪B)=100$.
If the question would have included also that *“every Indian likes at least one of the two fruits.”* then it would be fine to say $n(A∪B)=n(U)=100$, but how can we say that $n(A∪B)=100$ here?
**Edit** (1:51 PM, 23 March 20): Answer given 38%

Comment: You are right. The text book is wrong.  ... the book is assuming that it is a given that everyone likes at least one of the fruit. I just can't see that that should be a given.  I'd say the $76\le n(A\cup B)\le 100$ while $n(A\cup B) = 76 + 62 - n(A\cap B)$ so $n(A\cap B) = 138- n(A\cup B)$ so $138 -76= 62\ge n(A\cap B) \ge 100-76 = 24$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't; it may be that there are $100$ Indians, $62$ of whom like oranges and bananas, another $14$ of whom like oranges but not bananas, and $24$ of whom like neither fruit. This is a perfectly possible scenario based on the given data.

You're right: the question is missing information.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The text book is wrong.

... the book is assuming that it is a given that everyone likes at least one of the fruit. I just can't see that that should be a given.

We know that $n(A\cup B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A\cap B)$ so $n(A\cap B) = 138 - n(A\cup B)$.

But all we can say about $n(A\cup B)$ is $A\subset A\cup B$ and $B\subset A\cup B$ and $A\cup B\subset U$ so  $\max(n(A),n(B)) \le n(A\cup B) \le n(U)$ or $\max(62,78)=78 \le n(A\cup B) \le 100$.

So $138-78 = 62 \ge n(A\cap B) \ge 138-100 = 38$.

That's as tight as we can get it with this information.

If I'm to judge by the number of questions out there, there are a *lot* of bad texts out there.  By careful.

....

Oh.... that upper limit of $62$... Of course, we could have alternatively gotten that via $A\cap B \subset A$ and $A\cap B \subset B$ so $n(A\cap B) \le \min(n(A), n(B)) = \min(78,62) = 62$.